# Access point name settings are not available for this user / Samsung A14 5G from Tracfone

Tags: samsung, verizon, apn, tracfone

Samsung A14 5G SM-S146VL from Tracfone (part of Verizon) was bought for cheap from QVC.
Phone was unlocked after 2 months of service using the code received from Tracfone.
US Mobile SIM card inserted.
Calls and SMS work.
Mobile data does not work.
When I go to the APN settings it shows "Access Point Name settings are not available for this user".
"Add" option is greyed out.
"Reset to default" option under three dots is greyed out.

So, it seems like Verizon prohibited using their phones with other carriers even after unlocking them?

Any ways to solve this issue?
NO root, BL not unlocked.
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.
What I managed to do is to install My Tech Suite app (published by TheSheryar) from Play Store.

It allowed me to forcefully manually add APNs to the system when I was locked out of the standard way to do so in Settings.

So, I did the following (worked for US Mobile carrier, but vzwinternet access point should work for any MVNO using Verizon network):

Start the app, push "Add New APN" and enter the following APN settings:

APN name: Verizon 2
APN: vzwinternet
Multimedia Messages port: 80
MMSC: http://mms.vtext.com/servlets/mms
MCC: 311
MNC: 480
Apn protocol: iPv4/iPv6
Apn roaming protocol: iPv4/iPv6
APN type: default,supl
Add the APN > Click the 3 dots > Hit save and close the app.

APN name: Verizon CBS
APN: VZWAPP
MMSC: http://mms.vtext.com/servlets/mms
MCC: 311
MNC: 480
APN type: cbs,mms
APN Protocol: iPv4/iPv6
APN Roaming Protocol: iPv4/iPv6
Add the APN > Click the 3 dots > Hit save and close the app > Reopen the APP

APN name: Verizon IMS
APN: VZWIMS
MCC: 311
MNC: 480
APN type: ims,ia
APN Protocol: iPv4/iPv6
APN Roaming Protocol: iPv4/iPv6

Add the APN > Click the 3 dots > Hit save and close the app > Reopen the APP
After that, 5G data and MMS started working immediately.
Hope this helps somebody. :-)